# yield statement in myhdl

Tags: python, python-2.7, myhdl

I have the following code in my myhdl environment:

```
def rst(self):
   rst.next=rst.active
   self.wait_clks(5)

def wait_clks(self, cycles):
   for _ in range(cycles):
      yield self.clk.posedge
```

the above code doesn't work but when I replace it with the following it works:

```
def rst(self):
   rst.next=rst.active
   for _ in range(5):
      yield self.clk.posedge
```

I am confused over this, if anyone can explain why the yield in the function definition doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply call a `generator function` (one that has yield statement in its body) , you get a generator object, it does not even start going through the function at that point, it only starts that when you start iterating over the returned generator object (or call `next()` on it). Example -

```
>>> def gen1():
...     print("Starting")
...     for i in range(10):
...             yield i
...
>>> g = gen1()
>>> g
<generator object gen1 at 0x00273E68>
```

As you can see above, it did not start going through the function, it just returned the generator object. To go through the function you need to iterate over `g` or call `next()` on it. Example -

```
>>> g.next()
Starting
0
>>> for i in g:
...     print i
... 
1
2
.
.
```

In your first case as well something similar is happenning, you are just calling the generator function, which returns the generator object, and then discarding the result. Most probably, from wherever `rst()` is called , it is expecting a generator object in return. In which case your second method is the best.

But if you really really want to make it in a separate function (and I do not see any need to make it in a separate method) , you can directly return the result of `self.wait_clks(5)` back from `rst(self)` . Example -

```
def rst(self):
   rst.next=reset.active
   return self.wait_clks(5)
```

Example to show that this works -

```
>>> def f():
...     return gen1()
... 
>>> for i in f():
...     print(i)
... 
Starting
0
1
2
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

As described by Anand you can't simply call a generator, in this case if you yield the generator you will get what you expect"

```
def rst(self):
    rst.next=rst.active
    yield self.wait_clks(5)
```